# How to include apostrophe's to display a string

Tags: string, matlab

I'm trying to display to a user 'streamlines'. How would I do this?? I've tried using `disp()` with " inserted with failure.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Comment: MATLAB sorry about that

Comment: Do you want to use the quotes: `"`?

Comment: I want to use whatever it takes to be able to output 'streamlines' to the user

Comment: try with: `disp("'streamlines'")`

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes need to be escaped by placing a single quote in front of them.  Something like this:

```
username = '''streamlines'''
disp(username)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you´re asking how to write the apostrophe, right? if is that you just have to double the apostrophe and it will show up like just one. It would be like:  ''streamlines''.